# Word for a response that is enthusiastic, passionate and long-winded

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

For example, when asked "What did you put in your tea?"

A normal response might be "Honey."

A ______ response might be "The sweetest honey, from the greatest of flower orchards.  I could literally taste every sweet petal of the flowers that became the honey comb.  The flavor began as a light sweetness and then crescendo-ed into a grand orchestration of savory, blissfully sweet, yet earthy delights! I became enraptured and clenched my fists, looking towards the sky and exclaiming, *'WWWOOOOOOOWWWWW!!  That's some great honey!'*"

Comment: grandiloquent? Tall-talk? https://www.thoughtco.com/tall-talk-definition-1692525

Answer (score 1):

How's [effusive](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/effusive)?

> Effusive: marked by the expression of great or excessive emotion or
>   enthusiasm: effusive praise... We've used "effusive" in English to
>   describe excessive outpourings since the 17th century... A person
>   effuses when he or she speaks effusively...

Answer (score 0):

There are many possibilities. **Dithyrambic** is one of them, defined by [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dithyrambic) as

> (of a statement or writing)  in an exalted or enthusiastic vein

Answer (score 0):

There's [sesquipedalian](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sesquipedalian) and [prolix](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prolix) but I'm not sure they convey the senses of over-enthusiasm and passion. Perhaps [grandiloquent](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/grandiloquent). It means

> Pompous or extravagant in language, style, or manner

Comment: Ooh! I like `grandiloquent`.